# Redshift: Get hour from Time (HH:MM:SS) column

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a time column with values in HH:MM:SS format. How do I get only the hour from that column?

I have tried using extract(hour) function.

```
select extract(hour from opentime::datetime)
from transaction
```

I got an error saying Amazon Invalid operation: Timestamp out of range. I assume this is because the opentime column isn't exactly DateTime but only time.

I need to get only the hour.

```
column value --> 09:00:00
expected output --> 09
```

Comment: You might need to add a fake date, such as `extract(hour from ('2000-01-01 ' || opentime)::datetime)`

Comment: Hey John, That workaround worked. But I have many queries where I need to apply this and it's making the overall query performance slow. If you have any other ideas please do share and Thank you for your solution.

Comment: If the column is a string, then use: `LEFT(opentime, 2)::integer`

Comment: Hey John, Thanks this workaround gives better performance when querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input column is a string, then extract the hour with:

```
LEFT(opentime, 2)::integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a [`SUBSTRING`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUBSTRING.html) operation on `TIME` columns

```
select '13:21:23'::TIME as t, substring(t, 1, 2);
```

returns

```
t           hour
13:21:23    13
```

Comment: Hey botchniaque, I get this error "Invalid operation: Datatype not implemented" when executing '13:21:23'::time

Comment: Strange - which Redshift version are you at? I executed the above query against 1.0.8205